# странно работает ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

есть скрипт выводящий меню категорий, аяксом при нажатию на категорию подгружает из файла список дочерних категорий в отдельном блоке, при нажатии на категорию в этом блоке происходит перезагрузка страницы и выводятся следующие дочерние категории в этом же блоке, нажимая далее по категориям в этом же блоке уже срабатывает аякс, почему так странно работает скрипт?

скрипт который подгружает данные из файла

```
$(function(){
$(".get_url").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var getvalue = $(this).attr('href');
    var arguments = getvalue.split('?')[1].split('=');
    arguments.shift();  
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
     getContent(arguments,href, true);

});

});

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {       
    getContent(location.search, false);
});


function getContent(arg,url, addEntry) {

 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'menu.php?category=' + arg,
        success: function(html){    
         $(".content").html(html);   
          if(addEntry == true) {
            // Добавляем запись в историю, используя pushState
            history.pushState(null, null, url); 
        }
        }
   });
}
```

// меню вывода дочерних категорий

```
<?php include 'catalog.php'; ?>
            <?php foreach($get_catById as $cats_ById): ?>
        <a class="get_url"  href="<?=PATH?>?category=<?=$cats_ById['id']?>"><?=$cats_ById['title']?></a><br>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вангую что ваша проблема в этой строчке кода `$(".get_url").click(...`.

Поскольку вы подгружаете данные аяксом то событие не вешается на элемент с классом `.get_url`

Попробуйте сделать следующее `$(document).on('click', '.get_url', function(){...})`

Подробнее:

[Документация метода jquery.on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On)

[Разница между click() vs on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Comment: это сработало=)

Comment: отметьте галочкой

Comment: Вы можете принять ответ через 4 минуты, не разрешает сразу отметить

Comment: также я добавил ссылки, рекомендую почитать и использовать `$.on()` всегда вместо `$.click(), $.hover(),  etc`, это избавит вас от множества проблем